# Remove anything in between space and equal sign

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

`2014-01-09T06:16:53.748849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST fwd="94.66.255.106" dyno=web.12 connect=12ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=78`

and I would like it to be:

`2014-01-09T06:16:53.748849+00:00 heroku[router]: info POST "94.66.255.106" web.12 12ms 21ms 200 78`

I tried something like this:

```
/.*=/
```

but it matches anything between the first and last equal sign.

I'm sure replacing the first is ok, then using something like `gsub` to replace them all.

Comment: By the syntax of the regex, we're talking JavaScript regex are we not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `/.*=/` matches any characters but a newline up to the last `=` encountered on a line. It happens because `*` is a greedy quantifier, and matches as many characters as possible.

You seem to need to match substrings having no spaces right before `=`. You can use

```
s.gsub(/[^\s=]+=/, '')
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/uNokvf) and [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/zJkFgTZ5hC)

```
s = '2014-01-09T06:16:53.748849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST fwd="94.66.255.106" dyno=web.12 connect=12ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=78'
puts s.gsub(/[^\s=]+=/, '')
# => 2014-01-09T06:16:53.748849+00:00 heroku[router]: info POST "94.66.255.106" web.12 12ms 21ms 200 78
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^\s=]+` - 1 or more (due to `+` quantifier) characters other than whitespace and `=` (the `[^...]` is a negated character class, all characters not in it are matched)
- `=` - an equal sign

Comment: Is the "non-equals-sign" part really necessary? All it does is turn what would be 1 match for `example=thing=` into 2 matches.

Comment: @4castle: Backtracking is our friend when we need it to work for us, but here, we do not need that. For the pattern to work in a linear way, adjacent subpatterns should not match one another. 207 steps (mine) vs. 1005 (yours). I think my pattern performs better just because it involves much less backtracking.

Comment: Backtracking? Linear? I don't understand what you mean by these words in this context.

Comment: @4castle: Visit rexegg.com, regular-expressions.info, please read more on regex.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes sense now

Comment: I thought about it some more, and this is a nit picky observation, but it won't match something like `=example=` or `==`.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, the regex you want will select all strings (length 1+) that are non-whitespace characters and which come before an equals sign, including the equals sign.

`/\S+=/` is that regex. [Here's a demo.](https://regex101.com/r/uA2yF6/5)

Comment: **Update:** now using `\S` in order to select all non-space characters instead of all characters.

Comment: Now `(?:\s)` part is redundant.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thank you.

Comment: Now parentheses are redundant :)

Comment: @mudasobwa u da reel mvp

Comment: Actually, the best regex is `/[^\s=]+=/` here since `\S` matches `=` and `[^\s=]` does not.

Comment: Oh wait, @WiktorStribiżew version does :)

Comment: You do not need `/g` at rubular :) Ruby regex does not support that modifier.

Comment: @4castle If you are not eager to explain the pattern, I will have to post my answer. Just "many thanks" is not a good excuse to use other's patterns in your answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know how to explain it, but thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I will post my own answer then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is explained now. Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: Then check how your regex works (number of steps = 1005) and mine (207). Which is faster and why? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the greedy behavior of .* try this instead:

```
/.*?=/
```

Comment: What’s the essential meaning of square bracketing equal sign?

Comment: none, it is a personal taste in regex to put characters within brackets

Comment: It is not a great habit, since it might drastically decrease the productivity.